# Python: Return list result problem in a function

Tags: python, list, function, return

If I do this with print function

```
def numberList(items):
     number = 1
     for item in items:
         print(number, item)
         number = number + 1

numberList(['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green'])
```

I get this

```
1 red
2 orange
3 yellow
4 green
```

if I then change the print function to return function I get just only this:

```
(1, 'red')
```

why is this so?

I need the return function to work exactly like the print function, what do I need to change on the code or rewrite...thanks...Pls do make your response as simple, understandable and straight forward as possible..cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`return` ends the function, while `yield` creates a generator that spits out one value at a time:

```
def numberList(items):
     number = 1
     for item in items:
         yield str((number, item))
         number = number + 1

item_lines = '\n'.join(numberList(['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green']))
```

alternatively, `return` a list:

```
def numberList(items):
     indexeditems = []
     number = 1
     for item in items:
         indexeditems.append(str((number, item)))
         number = number + 1
     return indexeditems

item_lines = '\n'.join(numberList(['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green']))
```

or just use `enumerate`:

```
item_lines = '\n'.join(str(x) for x in enumerate(['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green'], 1)))
```

In any case `'\n'.join(str(x) for x in iterable)` takes something like a list and turns each item into a string, like `print` does, and then joins each string together with a newline, like multiple `print` statements do.

Comment: +1 for mentioning enumerate and your appending to a list solution (that's how I was going to answer it).

Answer (score 1):

A `return` function will `return` the value the first time it's hit, then the function exits. It will never operate like the `print` function in your loop.

Reference doc: http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return_stmt

What are you trying to accomplish?

You could always `return` a `dict` that had the following:

```
{'1':'red','2':'orange','3':'yellow','4':'green'}
```

So that all elements are held in the 1 return value.

Comment: I understand that, what I want is stated in my question

Comment: What you want is impossible unless you capture all elements in the 1 return object as I suggested or use `yield` as agf suggested. A `return` statement ends a function - it can't return multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The moment the function encounters "return" statement it stops processing further code and exits the function. That is why it is returning only the first value. You can't return more than once from a function.

Comment: This doesn't help him with how to do it.