# Python: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, list, function

I want to get this function to work:

```
def getEvenNumbers (numbers):

    bo = []
    for num in numbers:
         bo.append(num)
         if num % 2 == 0:
           return bo
```

`getEvenNumbers([1, 4, 8, 9])` returns `[4]` though.

I expect more result like `[4,8]` but it not working, I only get `[4]`? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: duplicate of [Python: Return list result problem in a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439513/python-return-list-result-problem-in-a-function) which you asked just a short time ago. Please read the answers to it more carefully, mine shows exactly how to do this -- accumulate to a list then return when finished.

Comment: yes...agf...I followed that step...the more reason am even confused about what am doing wrong

Comment: @agf How is this a dupe of that question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are returning as soon as one of the numbers is found to be even.

```
def get_even_numbers(numbers):
    bo = []
    for num in numbers:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            bo.append(num)
    return bo
```

Or:

```
def get_even_numbers(l):
    return [n for n in l if n % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: Ok, I'm just trying to get to the bottom of that.  It happened to me once before too and thought it was something I did.

Comment: thank NullUser...I can't believe that it just the position of the return function...thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Actually your code as given currently will return [1, 4], not [4].  Your function currently simply appends numbers to a list until it finds the first even one, after which it returns.

You want something like:

```
def getEvenNumbers(numbers):
    return [n for n in numbers if not n % 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def getEvenNumbers (numbers):

    bo = []
    for num in numbers:
         if num % 2 == 0:
           bo.append(num)
    return bo
```